# Creating a controller and I'm getting HTTP error 415 when trying to use HttpPost

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, blazor

Trying to create a controller in order to add an instance of a class to a SQL database

However, I keep getting a 415 error whenever I try to do. The error specifically shows the following ->

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-f30954ed2136f9135eeb829d54578d45-69a58efb9fadfcc2-00"}

at blazorTestApp.Client.Repositories.AuthorsRepo.AddAuthor(Authors Author)
   at blazorTestApp.Client.Pages.Authors.AddAuthor.OnSubmit()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

**The controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using blazorTestApp.Shared.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace blazorTestApp.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthorsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Database DB;
        public AuthorsController(Database DB)
        {
            this.DB = DB;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Post(Authors Author)
        {
            DB.Add(Author);
            await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Http service file**

```
namespace blazorTestApp.Client.Classes_FE
{
    public class HttpService : IHttpService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        public HttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponse<object>> POST<T>(string url, T data)
        {
            var JsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            var StringContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "applicaiton/json");
            var ResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, StringContent);
            return new HttpResponse<object>(null, ResponseMessage, ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

This file simply inherits from an interface that currently only contains the post method shown. Said interface is the one that is injected into the repository

**The repository that sends the Http service**

```
namespace blazorTestApp.Client.Repositories
{
    public class AuthorsRepo
    {
        private IHttpService httpService;
        private string url = "api/Authors";
        public AuthorsRepo(IHttpService httpService)
        {
            this.httpService = httpService;
        }

        public async Task AddAuthor(Authors Author)
        {
            var response = await httpService.POST(url, Author);
            if(!response.Success)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(await response.GetBodyString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Lastly, the file calling the "AddAuthors" method**

```
@page "/Authors/Add"
@inject AuthorsRepo authorRepo
@inject NavigationManager NavMan

@code
{
    public Authors Author {get; set;} = new Authors();
    public async Task OnSubmit()
    {
        //Unrelated code
        await authorRepo.AddAuthor(Author);
        NavMan.NavigateTo("Authors");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in Blazor that how you send the request to API?

Comment: I edited the post to showcase everything. Hope this clears it up more, sorry for the initial confusion

Comment: Looks like you have a typo error in `HttpService`, should be "application/json" but not "applicaiton/json"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `POST` method in `HttpService`,

```cs
var StringContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "applicaiton/json");
```

It should be "applica**ti**on/json" but not"applica**it**on/json".

While you can use [`HttpClientJsonExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync<TValue>(HttpClient, Uri, TValue, JsonTypeInfo<TValue>, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-6.0) which will also

> Sends a POST request to the specified Uri containing the value serialized as JSON in the request body.

```cs
public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    public async Task<HttpResponse<object>> POST<T>(string url, T data)
    {
        var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data);
        return new HttpResponse<object>(null, ResponseMessage, ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can't believe that was the error lol. It didn't solve the entire problem as it gave way to another error, but I guess I'll make another post for that if I couldn't find a solution online. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

@Yong Shun is right - we would need to have a look at your client-side / blazor-code to explicitly point out the culprit here.

Generally speaking you should verify the `Content-Type` attributes value. Most likely you are not sending the `Author` argument in `application/json` but e. g. in `text/plain`.

You can also check in the development-console of your browser. Have a look at you request and verify the `Content-Type` there. If it is anything other than `application/json` adapt accordingly on your client-side code.

Comment: I just edited the post to showcase anything that might have been missing. I apologize for the initial confusion. I also checked the dev console, but it looks like "Authors" is what's actually being sent. Additionally, in the request headers, the content type is "applicaiton/json; charset=utf-8"